# isAnnotationPresent returning false always

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Im trying to create my own annotation and parse it . But when i try to get the methods that has my annotation using reflection Im always getting false.

Googled custom annotations in web but still not able to find the exact issue  .

Below is the annotation class and the class that uses it and parse it.

**Annotation:**

```
package AnnotationsImpl;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {

    int custom_int() default 11; 
    String custom_str();

}
```

**Class where annotation is used :**

```
    package AnnotationsImpl;


    public class AnnotationImpl extends AnnotationExample {

        //@CustomAnnotation(custom_str="str1")   
        int a=2;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
         @CustomAnnotation(custom_str="str1")        

        public static void main(String[] args){
            AnnotationExample ai = new AnnotationExample();
            ai.overrideMethod();

            AnnotationImpl aaa = new AnnotationImpl();
            aaa.overrideMethod();

            aaa.testingCA();


            ai.myDeprecatedMethod();


        }

        @Override
        public void overrideMethod(){

            System.out.println("In child class");
        }

        @CustomAnnotation(custom_str="str1")        
        public static void testingCA(){

            System.out.println("custom annotation");
        }

    }
```

Parser :

```
    package AnnotationsImpl;

    import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;



    public class AnnotationParser {


        public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

            for(//AnnotationParser.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("AnnotationsImpl.AnnotationImpl")//
                    Method method : Class.forName("AnnotationsImpl.AnnotationImpl").getMethods()

                    ){

                System.out.print("method name :"+method.getName());
                System.out.print(" *** Custom annotation present :"+method.isAnnotationPresent(CustomAnnotation.class));

                System.out.println();

                if(method.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotationsImpl.CustomAnnotation.class)){

                    System.out.println("custom present");

                    for(Annotation ann : method.getDeclaredAnnotations()){



                        System.out.println("Annotation ann :"+ann +"=== method :::"+method);

                        CustomAnnotation cu = method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);

                    }
                }



            }

        }

    }
```

output :

```
*run:
method name :main *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :check *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :overrideMethod *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :testingCA *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :wait *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :wait *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :wait *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :equals *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :toString *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :hashCode *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :getClass *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :notify *** Custom annotation present :false
method name :notifyAll *** Custom annotation present :false
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)*
```

Tried RUNTIME retention policy.
Why am i getting annotation present false always ?What mistake have I done? Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why did you comment `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`?

Comment: Like @ernest_k pointed out, the `RUNTIME` retention is crucial. Also, packages name in Java are lower case ..

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k and eugen .I was learning custom annotation so was trying diff aspects where i tried source, class, runtime retention and then tried without retention .Thats y it was commented . I have edited the post.But even with runtime retention i got false. **Also, packages name in Java are lower** - i have named my package as AnnotationsImpl . Any issue in the code ?